# File Upload & Google Protobuf

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to send a file over a WebSocket using Google Protocol buffers.

My message structure for the buffer is

```
message FileData_m {
    required uint32 block = 1; // File starting offset
    required bytes data = 2;   // Size of 65536 for blocks
}
```

The idea is to break up the file into blocks and send it over a WebSocket. Currently I'm running a Node.js server that handles interactions between host and server I just don't know how to properly send the file in a binary manner.

Any help and/or pointing me in the right direction would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was to make sure that my data was being sent using an array buffer

```
var dataToSend = new ArrayBuffer(65536);
dataToSend = file; // File that was uploaded from file chooser
```

Then when creating your protobuf message just use that array buffer as your source of data

```
var FileData = new FileData({
  "block": 0,
  "data": dataToSend
});
```